# Unit Test Vuetify v-select @change event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

Can't write test which tests Vuetify `v-select` `@change` event. Event handler `select_change` doesn't called inside test.

**Demo.vue**

```html
    <div>
        <v-select @change="select_change" :items="[1,2,3]" v-model="value"></v-select>
    </div>
```

```js
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                value: 1,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            select_change() {
                console.log('inside select_change')
            }
        }
    }
```

**Demo.vue.test.js**

```js
    it('v-select@change', () => {
        wrapper = mount(Demo, {
            vuetify: new Vuetify
        })
        wrapper.setMethods({
            select_change: jest.fn(),
        })
        wrapper.find('.v-select').trigger('change', /* {value: 2} */)
        expect(wrapper.vm.select_change).toBeCalled()
    })
```

**test output**

> Error: expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()
>
> Expected number of calls: >= 1 Received number of calls:    0

Answer (score 4):

This is probably not the answer you want, but it's **not your job** to test the `<v-select>` component's `@change` event. This [event is already tested by the Vuetify team](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/__tests__/VSelect.spec.ts#L46) among the unit tests for this component. FWIW, it's fairly common for people to want to write tests like the one you describe.

However, your job is to make sure that *your* component (the one that *wraps* `v-select`) defines an appropriate interface/contract, and that it abides by it. Some examples of things you might reasonably test:

1. Does the list of items assigned to the `v-select` have exactly three elements that are 1, 2, and 3?
2. Does this component have a method called `select_change()` and does that function return expected values with given input? (BTW, your `select_change()` method doesn't currently return *any* values so is difficult to test)

Your tests might look something like:

```js
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import Demo from '@/components/Demo'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
const vuetify = new Vuetify()
const localVue = createLocalVue()

describe('A Demo component', () => {
  it('has a `v-select` with 3 items: [1, 2, 3]', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Demo, { localVue, vuetify })
    const items = wrapper.find('.v-select').props('items')
    expect(items.length).toBe(3)
    expect(items).toStrictEqual([1, 2, 3])
  })

  it('has item 1 selected by default', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Demo, { localVue, vuetify })
    expect(wrapper.find('.v-select').props('value')).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

As tempting as it may be to want to test the underlying functionality of the `v-select` component, you've got to trust that the Vuetify team did their job. :-)

Comment: Not agree. I need to rest this scenario: 1) user selects locale 2) select triggers event 3) correct eventhandler executes. This is common test. Many same tests present in official vie-test-utils and vuetify docs except they all about button@click event, but not select@change

Comment: [From the docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#knowing-what-to-test): "we recommend writing tests that assert your component's public interface, and treat its internals as a black box" A `v-select` triggering an event is **internal** to Vuetify's VSelect component and as such outside of what you should be testing. You can and should test things like: 1) Do you have a complete list of locales available for selection, and 2) Given some input, does your event handler do what is expected.

Comment: One paragraph after that written:For example, for the Counter component which increments a display counter by 1 each time a button is clicked, its test case would simulate the click and assert that the rendered output has increased by 1. And many-many button click simulation tests below.  So you can see that vue creatirs don,t think about  button click simulating as internal side of component. Button@click===select@change. Correct?

Comment: The key difference is that in the example, you are testing a button that you are implementing directly. You are not wrapping someone else's button inside your own component. In your example, you are wrapping Vuetify's `v-select` in your own component, so there's an additional level of nesting. It's a subtle but important difference.

Comment: Thank you for your time again. Realy I don't see any difference between doc's example and my code. See this code again. From my point of view it is completeley equal // counter.js https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#getting-started  In example we see button inside div. In my code we see v-select inside div. v-select, button or any other component should not be matter. They both emit events.

Comment: Vuetify has an [active Discord community](https://community.vuetifyjs.com/) with a channel for #testing. You're welcome to ask your question there. I expect you'll get the same answer that I gave you, since that is the same answer I've seen others in that channel receive when asking similar questions. At the very least you'll have the chance to have a conversation with someone about it.

Comment: Thank you very mutch, I didn't know about  discord channel. I know you think my test wrong. Maybe you can point another way how to test case  when 1. user selects locale using v-select component followed by rest api call method 2. check expectation that api.setLocale() have been called.